# Changing Lotus Notes jvm arguments cause splash screen loop

Tags: lotus-notes

I had really bad performance on lotus notes with the default parametres so I thought about changing in `jvm.properties` the following settings to higher values:

```
vmarg.Xmx=-Xmx1024m
vmarg.Xms=-Xms48m
vmarg.Xmca=-Xmca8k
```

The change was causing the Lotus Notes to stay in a loop at the `Loading ... please wait` splash screen. 
Switching back to default values seems to work.

Any Ideas what may cause this?

Comment: I changed Xmx and Xms on almost every of my installations and never had any issues... probably it was because of changing Xmca or you chose to big values for Xms...

Comment: I set `Xmca` to `512k` then lowered to `128k`, but didn't solve it. I'll try with default `Xmca`. The ram shouldn't be a problem, I have 16gb of RAM.